# XMLHttprequest is not defined in Gatsby-node + react-papaparse

Tags: reactjs, xmlhttprequest, gatsby, papaparse

I am new to react and gatsby, but it looks a little fun to learn. So my idea is to build a website that has a page from each row of Google Sheets. So you can say I want to make google sheets CMS. There are other easier tools to use for this, but some just stop developing and some are hella expensive to use. So I want to make it manually using papaparse plugin.

My google sheets are "published for web" in the form of CSV. I want to use react-papaparse for in-browser CSVtoJSON parsing. My gatsby-node.js is copying from the gatsby docs so it is a little barebone.

in my gatsby-node.js

```
const papaparse = require("react-papaparse")

exports.sourceNodes = ({ actions, createNodeId, createContentDigest }) => {
  const { createNode } = actions

  const myData = papaparse.readRemoteFile("published sheet links",{
    download: true,
    header: true,
    delimiter: ',',
    dynamicTyping: true,
  })

  const nodeContent = JSON.stringify(myData)

  const nodeMeta = {
    id: createNodeId(`my-data-${myData.key}`),
    parent: null,
    children: [],
    internal: {
      type: `MyNodeType`,
      mediaType: `text/html`,
      content: nodeContent,
      contentDigest: createContentDigest(myData)
    }
  }

  const node = Object.assign({}, myData, nodeMeta)
  createNode(node)
}
```

When I run, it throws **XMLHttpRequest is not defined** error in my google sheet links. So it seems about CORS problem?
What is the workaround for this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you won't be able to use `XMLHttpRequest` since it will be never available in the Node server (for obvious reasons), it will be available on your browser-side, but in your use-case, you need it to be available in the Node server, at the build-time, to create your schema.

You can try using some other fetching methods (`fetch`, axios, etc) or use some plugins like [`gatsby-source-google-sheets`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-google-sheets/). You just need to install the plugin and:

```
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-source-google-sheets',
    options: {
        spreadsheetId: 'get this from the sheet url',
        worksheetTitle: 'ie the name in the worksheet tab',
        credentials: require('./path-to-credentials-file.json')
    }
},
```

This will fetch in the build-time your sheets, creating the inferred GraphQL node schema

Resources:

- [https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/referenceerror-xmlhttprequest-is-not-defined-on-production-build~5bc45c69-36e1-4ad4-b8d6-495b5ec242bd](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/referenceerror-xmlhttprequest-is-not-defined-on-production-build%7E5bc45c69-36e1-4ad4-b8d6-495b5ec242bd)
- [Gatsby XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192396/gatsby-xmlhttprequest)
- https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/03/google-spreadsheets-and-javascriptnode-js.html
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/debugging-html-builds/

Comment: Just want to say WTF!!! Just know that gatsby-source-google-sheets exists, why the hassle using papaparse etc. 
Okay, will try that, thank you.

Comment: You can use your manual approach using the native `fetch` or axios, but global methods that need global objects (such as `window` or `document`) are not available on the server because they are not even created. In your case, since you need them to create the GraphQL schema, you'll need to change the approach.